# Can´t load a page on CEFSharp, Page is not rendered and no Error Thrown

Tags: c#, .net, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I´m trying to load a page, but only this address can´t get loaded, sometimes it flashes on the screen the page loaded, but immediately the page vanish.
I´m initializing it with :

```
var settings = new CefSettings();    
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath + @"\cache");
settings.LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Info;    
Cef.Initialize(settings);
browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?l=en&phone=15991078822");
this.Controls.Add(browser);
```

If I put any other address it will work nice, it works on chromium version 62.0.3189.0

**Update:**
Trying it on Cefclient (Cef browser example) the application returns the following error:

> **Page failed to load.**
>   URL: whatsapp://send?phone=15991078823
>   Error: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME (-302)
>   ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Open devtools to see what's going on. browser.ShowDevTools(); from memory

Comment: @amaitland It simple return a empty page, with <html> <head> and <body>. No Errors on console

Comment: I have the same issue: `Failed Provisional Load: whatsapp://send?phone=00000000000, error_code: -302, error_description: , showing_repost_interstitial: 0, frame_id: 2`. Using version 63.0.3.0

Comment: @pg02 I have managed to fix that, but don´t have the code now as I quit trying to use CEFSharp as it doesn´t work on an Web Application. But this have something to do with CefSharp treating protocols. In WebBrowsers when you have a protocol like whatsapp:// the browser tries to launch an especific application. You need to implement a interface that ignores that call. Something like that

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, that helped me 

Comment: @kosmosan can you please tell us how did you managaed this issue?